# How to execute ./process 2>&1 | tee log.txt with execvp

Tags: c, logging, process, execvp

I try to write a process controller. It should restart the process again every time it fails. Usually I start the process with the following terminal command:

```
./process 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

Now I want to execute this command with `execvp`:

```
int main() {
    int status;

    while(1) {
        pid = fork();
        char* const argv[4] = {"2>&1", "tee", "log.txt", NULL};

        if(pid == 0) {
            // make child process to ./process
            if(execvp("./process", argv) {
                perror("execvp");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else if(pid > 0) {
            sleep(3);
            // wait for ./process to return
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

This example program doesn't fail and ./process starts but `2>&1 | tee log.txt` is not executed or at least the log file doesn't appear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: redirection and such is a shell feature. You either have to implement it on your own (handle stdin/out etc in the code above) or start the process using /bin/sh. execvp( "/bin/sh", argv ), and add -e and ./process to argv. Also, "tee log.txt" should be two, not one, argument. In general, if you want this kind of things, use system().

Comment: In fact, just write your process controller in /bin/sh. There is no need to use C in this case, it only complicates things.

Comment: Can you give me an example how the process controller script should look like?

Comment: The equivalent to your C code (if fixed) would be  while : ; do ./process 2>&1| tee log.txt ; done

Comment: All right - may you can give your example as an answer (not comment)? I would appreciate if you could extend your example in a way that the log file has a different name every time the command gets executed again - for example log-TIMESTAMP.txt